# django admin like behaviour for app users

Tags: django, permissions, django-admin

We have `merchants` with `campaigns` in our project. Currently, we - as superuser - manage all merchants' campaigns. However, some merchants require access to campaign management so that they can control the process and set new campaigns themselves.

There is a possibility to create the second admin site and set permissions so that only merchants can log in. However, what we need is - to filter only the campaigns **owned by** logged in merchant and also, when creating a new one the `merchant_id` should be **prefilled and readonly**.

Is it possible to do it using the second django admin site or should I create a special frontend interface for this purpose? Is it possible to set permissions per user-object pair (in django admin)?

Edit: I found django-guardian https://github.com/django-guardian/django-guardian/blob/devel/README.rst that should be able to do what I need.

Comment: have a look at the (build in) roles and groups.

Comment: You can customise the `queryset` of your `ModelAdmin` by overriding the [`get_queryset()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_queryset) method. And you can customise the form used for adding/changing objects with [`get_form()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_form) or [`formfield_for_foreignkey()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_for_foreignkey) or look at the other methods on the page linked.

Comment: Also methods like [`has_change_permission()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.has_change_permission) will let you return permissions per object.

Comment: @dirkgroten thank you, it's exactly what I needed